# What algorithm is this `Object.is` polyfill referring to?

Tags: javascript

A polyfill for ES6's `Object.is` has been [posted](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019084207/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) as the following:

```js
if (!Object.is) {
  Object.is = function(x, y) {
    // SameValue algorithm
    if (x === y) { // Steps 1-5, 7-10
      // Steps 6.b-6.e: +0 != -0
      return x !== 0 || 1 / x === 1 / y;
    } else {
     // Step 6.a: NaN == NaN
     return x !== x && y !== y;
    }
  };
}
```

What are the steps *6.b-6.e* and *6.a* referring to, and what are they checking?

Comment: You must realize we cannot possibly know that.  This is code in response to some assignment or tutorial, and the tutorial has the steps.

Comment: It probably refers to some version of the JavaScript specification, but seemingly not [the current one](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevalue), which has been broken down into substeps that never get as high as numbering 10. Where did you get this polyfill? Source control history would probably help.

Comment: (As for what the actual *meaning* of those steps is, look at any documentation for [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), which will explain the distinctions from `===`; there are only a couple.)

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the ES 2015 specification link at the end of the MDN page, then the link to [SameValue](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-samevalue), you’ll find the list of steps it’s referencing:

> 6. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    a. If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.
>    b. If x is +0 and y is −0, return false.
>    c. If x is −0 and y is +0, return false.
>    d. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    e. Return false.

The purpose is to distinguish positive and negative zero (which `Object.is` does): in the case that `x === 0` and `x === y`, `1 / x !== 1 / y` if and only if x and y are differently-signed zeros, as `1 / 0` is `Infinity` and `1 / -0` is `-Infinity`.

(This is one of two behavior differences between `===` and `Object.is`, both also documented on the same MDN page.)

Comment: Step.6.a return x !== x && y !== y; NAN is number, I dont get It.

Comment: @JesseJSosmena: NaN is the only value in JavaScript that isn’t equal to itself, so `x !== x && y !== y` is only true if `x` and `y` are both NaN. As seen in the quote, `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` should indeed be true.